# Can propensity score analysis correct for reverse causation or simultaneity

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, reverse-causality, simultaneity

I have data where I suspect there may be reverse causation (Y => X) or simultaneity (Y <=> X). Does the technique of propensity score analysis help to account for this effect? I feel that as part of the technique we are constructing a "control"  equivalent sample (through propensity scores) which is counterfactual to any hypothesised simultaneity relationship.

EDIT :
Thanks. Can I add a bit more context? I have data on the sale price of houses (Y) in a neighbourhood and the local grocery retail provision (X). I am looking to see if the brand of the retail provision has an effect on the sales price of houses (in the UK this is known as a Waitrose effect, after a premium retailer brand (https://www.lloydsbankinggroup.com/Media/Press-Releases/2018-press-releases/lloyds-bank/090618_Supermarkets_LB/). My concern is that there might be simultaneity, with retail brands locating in areas with high house prices (Y => X) **and also** the presence of a particular retail brand raising house prices (X => Y). But maybe my concern is actually a *selection bias*, where certain retail brands are bias to select certain types of areas (high affluence/low affluence) and PS can correct for this?

Answer (score 1):

No. Matching methods in this case have the same fragility as regression. They do not automagically control for any [endogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endogeneity_(econometrics)) sources.

In assessment of treatment effect, both matching and regression base on the same Conditional Independence Assumption (CIA) (Angrist and Pishke, 2008), which is:

$$ \{Y_{0i}, Y_{1i}  \} \perp \! \! \!  \perp c_i | X_i $$

As long as treatment depends on outcome it is a straight violation of CIA and estimator in both methods is biased.

---

Angrist, Joshua D., and Jörn-Steffen Pischke. *Mostly harmless econometrics: An empiricist's companion*. Princeton university press, 2008.